# New DIV to appear on hover / mouseover of another Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseevent

I have a number of DIVs currently laid out in an oval shape. Each div represents a "service" and is ID'd accordingly, all are set with an absolute position.

What I am wanting to do is on mouseover of a div, I want to have a new DIV with relevant information appear in the middle. This should happen for each "service" so each "descriptive" div will be hidden until mouseover but all appear in the same space.

The website in question is the home page of www.faa.net.au.

How do I go about making this new descriptive DIV appear on mouseover and hide on mouseout?

Comment: I don't know that it's the correct solution, but what I have done in the past for this is create the `div`s that you are wanting and just make them hidden.  On `mouseover` of an element you can simply replace the `.html()` of the center div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is position all of those divs in that spot in the middle with CSS. They can stack and the z-index doesn't matter since all you'll only see one at a time. Then hide them with "display:none" in your CSS.

Then use jQuery's .hover() method to show those the appropriate div on mouseover

```
$("#idOftheDivYouHoverOn").hover(function (e) {
     //This funciton defines what happens on mouse-in or hover.

     $("#idOfTheDefaultCenterDiv").hide();
     $("#idOfTheDivYouWantedToShow").show();


}, function (e) {
    //This function defines what happens on mouse-out or when the hover is over.
    $("#idOfTheDefaultCenterDiv").show();
     $("#idOfTheDivYouWantedToShow").hide();

});
```

You'll have to do this for each one you hover on. There is a "smarter" way but it would be a very long answer to explain it.

That is if you want to do this using JavaScript/jQuery instead of just **plain CSS similar to the ones you see in other answers**. With this method you can add fading effects - take a look at jQuery's hover - http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Edit: Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/6dMDS/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Of the 3 answers given this is the only one that will actually work the way you want it too, or for that matter work at all.

Comment: OK, I am not quite sure what I am missing here or I have done something completely wrong but I cant seem to get it to work??

I have created a JS file called serviceHover.js which I have linked in my template and then just for the time being, assigned one of the services but nothing is happening.

I am not the best at this but I think I have missed something here!

Comment: Not sure if I have overcomplicated this by including another DIV but I was trying to get it to work and couldnt so reading the script above, I thought I would need an additional centreDiv, is this correct or have I just screwed it all up? lol

Comment: Thanks for that JS Fiddle, made a world of difference, I had a couple of things in the wrong place. :-)

Answer (score 0):

A friend in another forum just posted another way of doing this. Be warned it's CSS3 only so some browsers (and definitely older IE's) won't support it.

```
<div class="container">

<img class="one" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
<img class="two" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /><br>
<img class="three" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
<img class="four" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /><br>
<img class="five" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
<img class="six" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />


<div class="hidden-one">hidden-one</div>
<div class="hidden-two">hidden-two</div>
<div class="hidden-three">hidden-three</div>
<div class="hidden-four">hidden-four</div>
<div class="hidden-five">hidden-five</div>
<div class="hidden-six">hidden-six</div>

</div>

* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.container {width: 400px;}

.one:hover ~ .hidden-one,
.two:hover ~ .hidden-two,
.three:hover ~ .hidden-three,
.four:hover ~ .hidden-four,
.five:hover ~ .hidden-five,
.six:hover ~ .hidden-six
{display: block;}


.hidden-one,
.hidden-two,
.hidden-three,
.hidden-four,
.hidden-five,
.hidden-six
{
width: 200px;
height: 300px;
border: 1px solid red;
display:none;
float: right;
position: relative;
top:-305px;
left: 10px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LbfCl

Answer (score -1):

So if I got it right, you got a "service" DIV and a "descriptive" DIV. Try some CSS to make it happen.

HTML:

```
<div id="service"></div>
<div id="descriptive"></div>
```

And CSS:

```
#descriptive
{
visibility:hidden;
}

#service:hover #descriptive
{
visibility:visible;
}
```

Basically this will make the DIV with `id="descriptive"` be shown when `id="service"` is hovered.

Comment: O.o no... no it won't. CSS isn't conditional like that.  http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/FZApK/